# Dot product or multiplication

Tags: python, linear-regression

Gradient Descent Algorithm for Linear Regression:

Prediction: Use the current values of    and    to calculate the predicted values:

_pred = ⋅+

I just wanted to make sure that ⋅ is the dot product and not multiplication.

```
y_pred = np.dot(w,x) + b
```

do i use the dot product here or just do:

```
y_pred = w * x + b
```

Comment: NB: the dot notation denotes a dot product and not multiplication for vectors. A product would be written as `wx`.

Answer (score 0):

For Linear Regression you have you use

```
y_pred = w * x + b
```

Here
w is the weight
x is the input
b is the bias

Comment: Why do you assume `w` and `x` are scalars and not vectors?

Answer (score 0):

If w and/or x are scalars, both options you showed are equivalent.

If w and x are vectors, yes you should use `np.dot(w,x)`, as `w * x` will cause undesired results, such as receiving a vector result instead of a scalar result.

This could cause TypeErrors later in your code, depending on what it's used for.

Comment: It won't raise a TypeError, but will lead to an undesired result. E.g. `w = [1, 2], x = [3, 4],` results in `[3, 8]` as opposed to 11.